# error with pymtp to work on python 3

Tags: android, python-3.x, pymtp

I want to access a android device from python to download some photos.
libmtp works from the CLI.
Than [pymtp](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyMTP).  It's been around for a while but it's designed for python 2 and i'm using python 3. Meanwhile fixed several minor issues but i'm stuck at an error from function get_filelisting
specially this section:

```
ret = []
next = files
while next:
    ret.append(next.contents)
    if (next(next.contents) is None):
        break
    next = next(next.contents)
```

The error is related to the "next".

That section looks strange to me, i've been coding in python for a while  but i'm new to ctypes. Tried a lot of variants, they all failed. The "next" could be confusing with python buildin function so i renamed it to nextpointer and came to this code:

```
ret = []
nextpointer = files
while nextpointer:
    ret.append(nextpointer.contents)
    nextpointer = nextpointer.contents.next
```

It seems to work but did it work by accident ? does it have any design flaws ? Could anyone with experience on python ctypes confirm this a solution ?  Any suggestion welcome.

Answer (score 1):

From python2.7 documentation

> next(iterator[, default])
>
> Retrieve the next item from the iterator by calling its next() method. If default is given, it is returned if the iterator is
>   exhausted, otherwise StopIteration is raised.

from python3 documentation

> next(iterator[, default])
>
> Retrieve the next item from the iterator by calling its __next__() method. If default is given, it is returned if the iterator is
>   exhausted, otherwise StopIteration is raised.

Notice that next() **method** was removed from python3 but the **function** still exists.

This is all I can say about the next function and .next()/__next__() methods.

I downloaded the pymtp module and get_filelisting() is slightly different from what you posted in your ported code, here it is:

```
ret = []
next = files
while next:
    ret.append(next.contents)
    if (next.contents.next == None):
        break
    next = next.contents.next
```

If none of this helped you (which probably didn't :D), the version of pymtp library that I am using is 0.0.6 download using pip.